# Are the minimum of two symmetric matrices closer to each other than the two matrices themselves?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Consider any two real symmetric matrices $A,B\in\mathbb{S}^n$ with spectral decompositions: $$A=U_A D_A U_A',\quad B=U_BD_BU_B'$$ Now, let $$A^-\equiv U_A\min(D_A,0)U_A',\quad B^-=U_B\min(D_B,0)U_B'$$ where $\min(D,0)$ operates on every entry on the diagonal.

Is there any matrix norm such that $\forall A,B\in\mathbb{S}^n$:
$$\|A^--B^-\|\leq\|A-B\|$$

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ fixed? Or do you want to find a norm such that the inequality holds for every pair of matrices $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity. I would like to know if there is a norm for which the inequality holds $\forall A,B\in\mathbb{S}_n$.